# SQL query or sub-query?

Tags: sql, mysql

I've got a table of student information in MySQL that looks like this (simplified):

```
|   age : int   |   city : text   |   name : text   |
-----------------------------------------------------
|               |                 |                 |
```

I wish to select all student names and ages within a given city, and also, per student, how many other students in his age group (that is, how many students share his age value).

I managed to do this with a sub-query; something like:

```
select 
   name, 
   age as a, 
   (select 
       count(age) 
    from 
       tbl_students 
    where 
       age == a) 
from 
   tbl_students 
where 
   city = 'ny'
```

But it seems a bit slow, and I'm no SQL-wiz, so I figure I'd ask if there's a smarter way of doing this. The table is indexed by age and city.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select 
    t1.name, 
    t1.age as a, 
    count(t2.age) NumberSameAge
from 
   tbl_students t1 inner join tbl_students t2
    on t1.age=t2.age
where 
   city = 'ny'
group by t1.name, t1.age
```

not tested, but something like that. I.o.w. a groupby on a join. This sometimes can be faster as the query you're running is doing a nested subquery for *every* row returned, and the query I posted above (or at least, the structure with a join and a groupby) performs a query on the related students just once.

Comment: ooh.. never thought of doing a join on the same table. clever.. I'll try it out next week.

Comment: While a self-join is the right idiom for this query, I wanted to point out that you're perpetuating a bit of a myth in your justification. Correlated subqueries are generally optimized by the database engine into joins. Only rarely will it execute the nested query for each row. It's important to recognize when a subquery is the best syntax for a particular task; often, a subquery is clearer in its intent, and sometimes it's the only way to get a correct result. I don't have MySQL installed on this machine, but try `EXPLAIN`ing both queries – they might be more similar than you think.

Comment: It's worth point out, however, that MySQL's query optimizer is pretty much huffing and puffing behind every other major DBMS available. Your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 1):

It might be easier to grab a sub-query that grabs everything at once (vs. 1000 rows where it runs the sub-query 1000 times).

```
SELECT Age, count(*) AS SameAge FROM tbl_students
```

Making the full query:

```
SELECT t.Name, t.Age, s.SameAge
FROM tbl_students t
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT Age, count(*) AS SameAge FROM tbl_students
  ) AS s
    ON (t.Age = s.Age) -- m:1
WHERE t.City = 'NY'
```